# Extract tweet message from json generated by GetTwitter and put to file with Apache NiFi

Tags: twitter

Good afternoon SuperUser folks.

I've been lately reading lot of useful answers posted here, that helped me with previous doubts I had. I've decided to join the community and post my first question. Already investigated previously if there are answers, but couldn't find a workaround to my issue.

I'm new to Apache NiFi. I need to set a very simple flow which is getting some specific tweets from Twitter, extract the message from it and write to to a local folder.

If I am not mistaken, the flow is as simple as putting 3 processors: GetTwitter --> EvaluateJsonPath --> PutFile.

Looks like the EvaluateJsonPath is not doing the job of extracting the tweet's message from the json. In its properties tab, I've set the following:

- Destination: flowfile-attribute;
- Return-type: auto-detect
- Path Not Found Behavior: ignore
- Null Value Representation: empty string

I then added a property as below:

- twitter.msg: $.text

The whole flow is working, tweets are captured and go through the EvaluateJsonPath and then to PutFile, which is writing all coming tweets in (almost) real time, to a specific folder in my PC.

However, the files I see written in my folder, are json with all the attributes of a tweet. I am getting the same result as if I had connected the GetTwitter processor directly to PutFile!

Does anyone have a clue on what am I doing wrong? Maybe is there a better solution to make it happen?

Remember my target: I want to pick only the messages from all tweets and store them in my PC. Additional question: is it possible to store those messages as .txt format?

Thanks very much in advance for everyone reading my question and posting an answer if there is one :)

Kind regards,
Luis Pastor